# How can I modify the dropout rate in tensorflowjs after using loadFrozenModel?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I train the model in tensorflow,the model has dropout layer.And then I convert it into tensorflowjs ,then I load it by loadFrozenModel(),Can I modify the dropout rate after `model=tf.loadFrozenModel`?

Answer (score 2):

Currently frozen models  cannot be trained further. You can of course use them as a base for a transfer learning task, but the variables inside that model are frozen and not marked as updatable.

Using transfer learning, you can retrieve the layer before the dropout layer and change the dropout layer and train further